# Check if ipv6 is inside range

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ipv6

I have the maxmind's ipv6 data. Here's my current table (with sample data):

```
+---------------+------------+
|    network    | geoname_id |
+---------------+------------+
| 2001:208::/32 |        123 |
| 2001:218::/32 |       4312 |
+---------------+------------+
```

Using [their converter](https://github.com/maxmind/geoip2-csv-converter), I can create a `network_start_ip`and `network_last_ip` columns:

```
+------------------+----------------------------------------+------------+
| network_start_ip |            network_last_ip             | geoname_id |
+------------------+----------------------------------------+------------+
| 2001:200::       | 2001:200:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff |        123 |
| 2001:208::       | 2001:208:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff |       4312 |
+------------------+----------------------------------------+------------+
```

I was expecting that something like this would work (even though it would probably be slower than other methods):

```
SELECT b.geoname_id FROM blocks b 
WHERE HEX(INET6_ATON('2001:201:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff')) BETWEEN HEX(b.network_start_ip) AND HEX(b.network_last_ip)
```

So, what am I missing? Also, what is the best way to store ipv6 addresses (ranges)

Thank you

Comment: @PaulSpiegel It doesn't work, plus I would prefer to avoid string style comparisons since they are slower

Comment: What about `INET6_ATON('2001:201:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff') BETWEEN INET6_ATON(b.network_start_ip) AND INET6_ATON(b.network_last_ip)`?

Comment: Comparing indexed strings is faster than to convert a string to NUMERIC/BINARY.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Doesn't work either. Neither does this:
`WHERE HEX(INET6_ATON('2001:201:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff')) BETWEEN HEX(INET6_ATON(b.network_start_ip)) AND HEX(INET6_ATON(b.network_last_ip))`

Comment: The IP you are checking is not in any of the two ranges in your sample data.

Comment: That is what network masks are for, and masking is how network equipment does it. Mask the address in question, and if the result matches the network, then the address is in the network. Masking is lust a bitwise **AND** of the address and the mask.

Comment: No, ...:201:... is _not_ included in either range.  (The /32 is not at issue.)

Comment: Typo?  Before, you have 208 and 218; after converting, you have 200 and 208.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I've got it working:

1. Created another table with the same columns, but `network_start_ip` and `network_last_ip` are `VARBINARY(16)`
2. Populated that table with this statement: `INSERT INTO blocks
   SELECT INET6_ATON(b2.network_start_ip), INET6_ATON(b2.network_last_ip), b2.geoname_id FROM blocks_copy b2;`
3. Then, to check if the IPv6 address is in the range, I just need to run this query: `SELECT geoname_id FROM blocks b
   WHERE INET6_ATON('2a01:4ff:ffff:ffff::ffff') BETWEEN b.network_start_ip AND b.network_last_ip`

Comment: This solution sounds good, I am also working with this dataset, did this approach work for you with IPv4 too?

Comment: Does the last query (`SELECT geoname_id ......`) ensures that only 1 result is returned? I just tested about 15 IPv6 and each test did return only 1 result, but I would appreciate if you could confirm that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The original `HEX(...)` was unnecessary, as you seem to have observed in your self-Answer.  That is `BINARY(16)` is happy to correctly compare IPv6 values.

If you have a zillion rows in the table, you will find that that the queries are sloooow.  This is because no index can consistently help the Optimizer.  It is possible to do fast queries, but it involves getting rid of the last_ip column and padding the table with any missing ranges.  I discuss this, with code, [*here*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/ip-range-table-performance/).