# Convert IPv6 range in CIDR format to an IPv6 address range (start and end ips) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ipv6, cidr, geolite2

I am trying to import GeoLite2 ip to country csv file to my MySQL database. I was succesfully able to do that, however, to use it to search for IPs in my queries I need to create two more fields in both the ipv4 and ipv6 tables to store the start_ip and end_ip values for each CIDR range given (GeoLite csv files specify only the range in CIDR format).

I was able to convert this correctly for ipv4 address ranges using the solution given here
[Importing MaxMind's GeoLite2 to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019915/importing-maxminds-geolite2-to-mysql/32020220#32020220)

So I used

```
INET_ATON(SUBSTRING(network, 1, LOCATE('/', network) - 1))
```

for start_ip and

```
INET_ATON(SUBSTRING(network, 1, LOCATE('/', network) - 1)) + (POW(2, (32-CONVERT(SUBSTRING(network, LOCATE('/', network) + 1), UNSIGNED INT)))-1)
```

for end_ip. network is the name of the field where the CIDR range is stored.

However this does not work for IPv6 address ranges in CIDR format. I tried using INET6_ATON instead of INET_ATON but it gives me a numeric value out of range error. I am not much knowledgeable about IPv6 addresses so finding a formula myself is not easy.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and found the following [blog post](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-storing-ipv6/) that suggests how to get what you are looking for. I took inspiration from that post but modified it some. Here is my solution:

```
    DELIMITER //

    -- Returns the network address using an IPv4 address and the network length.
    CREATE FUNCTION ipv4_subnet(ip BINARY(4), net_len int) RETURNS BINARY(4)
        DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        DECLARE zeroIp BINARY(4) DEFAULT b'0';
        RETURN ip & (~zeroIp << (32 - net_len));
    END
    //

    -- Returns the host mask of an IPv4 address given the network length.
    CREATE FUNCTION ipv4_host_mask(net_len int) RETURNS BINARY(4)
        DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        DECLARE zeroIp BINARY(4) DEFAULT b'0';
        RETURN ~zeroIp >> net_len;
    END
    //

    -- Returns the network address using an IPv6 address and the network length.
    CREATE FUNCTION ipv6_subnet(ip BINARY(16), net_len int) RETURNS 
    BINARY(16)
        DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        DECLARE zeroIp BINARY(16) DEFAULT b'0';
        RETURN ip & ((~zeroIp << (128 - net_len)));
    END
    //

    -- Returns the host mask of an IPv6 address given the network length.
    CREATE FUNCTION ipv6_host_mask(net_len int) RETURNS binary(16)
        DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        DECLARE zeroIp BINARY(16) DEFAULT b'0';
        RETURN (~zeroIp >> net_len);
    END
    //
```

Note that I plan to store both the IPv4 and IPv6 from and to addresses in the same table declared as a `VARBINARY(16)`. Also, I switched to declaring a `BINARY(4|16)` for the functions I declared rather than calling `INET6_ATON` because I found that `INET6_ATON('0.0.0.0');` returns `0x00` and declaring the return as `BINARY` guarantees it will be left padded with the zero's you want for the methods and doesn't depend on the behavior of the `INET6_ATON` function. I suspect that this implementation may be better in performance as well but I haven't done any testing to prove that, but it is simply more straightforward, in my opinion, to declare a `BINARY` of a certain size and set it to `0` than to depend on the behavior of another function that returns a `VARBINARY` to do that for you.

You then determine the range for an IPv4 addresses and IPv6 addresses similar to what is suggested in the blog post. If you wanted to define functions for them:

```
    -- Determine from range for IPv4 address in CIDR format.
    CREATE FUNCTION ipv4_from_addr(ip BINARY(4), net_len int) RETURNS BINARY(4)
        DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        RETURN ipv4_subnet(ip, net_len);
    END
    //

    -- Determine to range for IPv4 address in CIDR format.
    CREATE FUNCTION ipv4_to_addr(ip BINARY(4), net_len int) RETURNS BINARY(4)
        DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        RETURN ipv4_subnet(ip, net_len) | ipv4_host_mask(net_len);
    END
    //

    -- Determine from range for IPv6 address in CIDR format.
    CREATE FUNCTION ipv6_from_addr(ip BINARY(16), net_len int) RETURNS BINARY(16)
        DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        RETURN ipv6_subnet(ip, net_len);
    END
    //

    -- Determine to range for IPv6 address in CIDR format.
    CREATE FUNCTION ipv6_to_addr(ip BINARY(16), net_len int) RETURNS BINARY(16)
        DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        RETURN ipv6_subnet(ip, net_len) | ipv6_host_mask(net_len);
    END
    //
```

I know your question was only about IPv6, but since one response suggested you could do both IPv4 and IPv6 with `INET6_ATON`, I thought I'd answer his thought as well.

**EDIT: 7/25/2022**
I just realized that the functions to determine the "to" addresses don't need to call the subnet functions. In other words:

```
    -- Determine to range for IPv6 address in CIDR format.
    CREATE FUNCTION ipv6_to_addr(ip BINARY(16), net_len int) RETURNS BINARY(16)
        DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        RETURN ip | ipv6_host_mask(net_len);
    END
    //

    -- Determine to range for IPv4 address in CIDR format.
    CREATE FUNCTION ipv4_to_addr(ip BINARY(4), net_len int) RETURNS BINARY(4)
        DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        RETURN ip | ipv4_host_mask(net_len);
    END
    //
```

should suffice (and be slightly more efficient since you are doing fewer operations).

Answer (score 0):

Use a column of type VARBINARY(16) to store the values.
And you can use INET6_ATON for both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-aton

Comment: My question was not how to store IPv6 values. I specifically asked how to convert a CIDR to starting and ending ips in the range using a query in MySQL. I even gave the query that I used to convert ipv4.

Comment: The problem you describe looks like an **overflow**, which can be expected here, because the size of an IPv6 address is 128 bits whereas UNSIGNED INT will only accommodate 4-byte (=32 bits) integer values up to a maximum value of 2147483647. See [Mysql Integer Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html). This is just fine for IPv4 addresses but not IPv6. BIGINT will not suffice either because the limit is 2^64 -1. This is not enough to handle IPv6 addresses.
So I would recommend some preprocessing before importing to Mysql.

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42414946/check-if-ipv6-is-inside-range) can help too.

Comment: Figured out that converting an IPv6 CIDR range is not as straightforward as the IPv4 version that it can be run in a single query or statement, so managed to solve this using a  custom function to convert the CIDR format to its corresponding start and end IPs

Comment: @AhmedShefeer, IPv6 is easier because the address is broken into two 64-bit parts (Network ID and Interface ID). the first address is the 64-bit network followed by `::`, and the last address is the 64-bit network followed by `:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff`. (Unlike IPv4, the all-zeroes and all-ones addresses are valid host addresses.) First address = `<network>::`; last address = `<network>:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my tool for converting MaxMind GeoLite2 country/city CSV to MySQL/PostgreSQL/Microsoft SQL Server 2019 from GitHub https://github.com/mbto/maxmind-geoip2-csv2sql-converter

You can read [examples](https://github.com/mbto/maxmind-geoip2-csv2sql-converter/wiki/Examples), or follow this steps:

1. Take a free license key to MaxMind API (if you don't have) at https://support.maxmind.com/account-faq/license-keys/how-do-i-generate-a-license-key/
2. Install Java 11 (if not installed) at [adoptopenjdk.net](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot) or [github.com/raphw/raphw.github.io](https://github.com/raphw/raphw.github.io/blob/master/openjdk/openjdk.csv) or [oracle.com/java](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html)
3. Download a tool from [releases](https://github.com/mbto/maxmind-geoip2-csv2sql-converter/releases) (.zip or .tar)
4. Unpack to yours directory
5. Copy/Paste .ini template `bin/GeoLite2-Country-CSV.mysql.default.ini` with your profile name, example `bin/GeoLite2-Country-CSV.mysql.Your Project Name.ini` or use default.
6. Open .ini template with Notepad and change `[windows_loader]` or `[unix_loader]` section (set MySQL host:port, user and password).
7. For unix: Execute `chmod +x maxmind-geoip2-csv2sql-converter`
8. Run converting: `maxmind-geoip2-csv2sql-converter.bat -c "GeoLite2-Country-CSV.mysql.Your Project Name.ini" -k Your_License_Key -i 4,6`
9. After converting, the scripts `bin/converted/loader.bat` and `bin/converted/loader.sh` will be available.
10. For unix: Execute `chmod +x loader.sh`
11. Execute `loader.bat` or `loader.sh` for importing schemas.

Done

[image: schemas]